# How do I best save/read data structures?

Tags: common-lisp, clos

I want to write some data structures pointed to by `FOO` and `BAR` to a file, and to read the data structures back into the symbols `FOO` and `BAR` when I start a new session of Common Lisp.

It would appear `*PRINT-READABLY*` allows objects to be printed in a fashion that can be read back in by `READ`, and I can change how objects are printed using `(defmethod print-object ...)`. Since the objects should be printed in a way acceptable to `READ`, I shouldn't have to define any further methods for reading the object back in.

But is there a way to tie each written data structure to its corresponding symbol, without having to rely on the order the data structures are written and read in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could store the values and associated symbols as pairs in the file, so something like this:

```
(x . (1 2 3 4))
(y . (6 7 8 1))
```

And when you parse it out, use something like this:

```
(let ((pair (read))
  (set (car pair) (cdr pair)))
```

Comment: Note that `(x . (1 2 3 4))` is an object with the same shape as `(x 1 2 3 4)`.

Comment: Yes, although from the OP's question it sounds like he will us other data structures. Besides lists.